# Azure Data Lake Gen2 REST API : http header missing for a flush action

Tags: azure, api, blob

Can any help on my following usage of Azure Data Lake Gen2 REST API. when I am going to flush to data to the file, it has error :

"message": "An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified

[image]

Error message after adding the header x-ms-date

[image]

My Steps :
Step 1
PUT   https://.dfs.core.windows.net/mydatalakefs/testing.json?resource=file

Header
Content-Length : 0
x-ms-version:2018-11-09
Authorization :Bearer

Step 2 
PATCH https://.dfs.core.windows.net/mydatalakefs/testing.json?action=append&position=0

Header
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Length:15
x-ms-version:2018-11-09
Authorization :Bearer

Body 
{"name":"1234"}

Step 3
Patch https://.dfs.core.windows.net/mydatalakefs/testing.json?action=flush&position=15

header
Content-Length:0
x-ms-version:2018-11-09
Authorization :Bearer 
x-ms-date: Mon, 24 Sep 2019 05:53:53 GMT

Answer (score 0):

**Update 0924:**

You should do the append action first, then do the flush action:

**step 1:**

append action, make sure the json length is correct. Then in postman:

In headers:

[image]

In body, input the json:

[image]

**step 2:**

Then do the flush action in postman:

[image]

---

The error message gives a tip but not detailed. Actually, you're missing the required header:  `x-ms-date` .

So please add `x-ms-date` and it's value(UTC/GMT format) in the request header like below:

```
x-ms-date: Mon, 23 Sep 2019 05:53:53 GMT
```

For how to generate the value for x-ms-date, using power shell as example:

In power shell, using this line of code: `[System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("R")`

Comment: Hi Ivan. Added the header x-ms-date but sill got the same error.

Comment: @MichaelChau, the flush action should be followed by the append action. Did you do the append action previously?

Comment: @MichaelChau, please refer to my updated answer for the steps of how to append and flush.

Comment: patch , action=append

body is json

Comment: @MichaelChau, I have updated my post, please refer to my steps. It works fine at my side.

Comment: yes. I added the header for x-ms-date but not working

Comment: @MichaelChau, can you provide a detailed steps, like how to append and flush? I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: I added my steps

Comment: any more hints . that's really strange? is it problem of the blob storage version ?

Comment: @MichaelChau, I didn't see any issue from your steps, and the same steps work at my side. very strange.

Comment: The only difference is that I also added the x-ms-date header in step 2. And I didn't use your step 1, I manually uploaded a empty file to ADLS gen2.

Comment: So are there anymore difference? manually uploaded a empty file ?

Comment: @MichaelChau, you can take a try by uploading an empty file, then use rest api for append / flush, remember add x-ms-date header for append and flush. There is no more difference.